# reporting services 2005 with sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssrs

Can you have Reporting services running on a SQL 2005 server connect and retrieve data from a SQL 2008 server, both x64 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a SQL 2008 database as the data source for a report.  The data source you connect to is independent of the version of reporting services you are using.